# Jquery Validator - check input against a list of accepted values

Tags: jquery, validation

I would normally just do this with a drop down list but the client has requested that it be a text input...

Basically, I'd like to use Jquery validator to check that a user has entered 1 of 50 valid US state abbreviations into a text input box.  If not, they'll get an error.  I can't seem to find a function that does this.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's a validation method you can add for use with [jquery validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

First you declare a validator:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("isstate", function(value) {
    var states = [
        "AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "FL", "GA",
        "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD",
        "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ",
        "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC",
        "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VT", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY",
        "AS", "DC", "FM", "GU", "MH", "MP", "PR", "PW", "VI"
    ];
    return $.inArray(value.toUpperCase(), states) != -1;
}, "Data provided is not a valid state");
```

Then apply the validator

```
$("#myform").validate()
```

and in your form you want to add the class to the form element to check

```
<input type="text" value="de" class="isstate" />
```

Here's a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/uHZY9/)

Comment: Mcgrailm, Thank you!  This is exactly what I am looking for, but I am getting this in my FireFox error console: Error: states.toUpperCase is not a function.

Comment: sorry that was suppose to go on value as value is a string that needs to be upperCase in order to check that its in the array I think it case sensitive anyway

Comment: @Mcgrailm I tried `jQuery.validator.addMethod("isstate", function(value.toUpperCase()) { 
    var states = ['PA',"CA"] // of course you will need to add more
  return $.inArray(value,states); 
}, "Data provided is not a valid sate");
` - which does not seem to be correct.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @paul I forgot that inarray returns -1 instead of false so I had to change the code to work around that

Comment: @Mcgrailm - man, thanks, I can't figure out why this isn't working! my form is at: http://173.45.237.55/qrf/ - does that look right? I've put your example on the top left as "Test valid state field..."

Comment: @paul you need to put the validation method in the $(document).ready() before you apply the validator

Comment: In case it helps anyone... here is the exact function I ended up using: 
`jQuery.validator.addMethod("isstate", function(value) {
    var states = [,"AK","AZ","AR","CA","CO","CT","DE","DC","FL","GA","HI","ID","IL","IN","IA","KS","KY","LA","ME","MT","NE","NV","NH","NJ","NM","NY","NC","ND","OH","OK","OR","MD","MA","MI","MN","MS","MO","PA","RI","SC","SD","TN","TX","UT","VT","VA","WA","WV","WI","WY"
]
    var in_array = $.inArray(value.toUpperCase(), states);
    if (in_array == -1) {
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}, "Please enter a valid US state");`

Comment: This answer helped me with my problem. Here is a variation on the syntax that I ended up going with! http://jsfiddle.net/uHZY9/9/ (Note: I reversed the logic to have a blacklist of values)

Comment: @rtpHarry what did you add this for .substr(0, 2) ?

Comment: @mcgrailm - I was validating a UK post code for delivery cost calculations. It contains more characters after this. I only wanted the first two characters which describes the postal district and allowed me to identify if it was in the Scottish Highlands. (thanks for your original code btw :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [change() listener](http://api.jquery.com/change/) that simply checks the input against your list of valid input strings and only enable submit buttons if you have a match.

Anyways. For user experience, it is better to show a dropdown selector list of all the possible states. At least that is what I thought first, when I reaad your question.

Regards,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dirty quick solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/naveed_ahmad/CqXZu/1/