# jQuery/Javascript: Efficient method to check user text input against a very large list of possible cases

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have created a 'check if we deliver to you' button on my site in jQuery.

The postcodes are put into an array, and the user input is checked against the array when the form is submitted.

There are approx. 10,000 postcodes to check against - which creates quite a large js file.

It seems to work no problem, but I expect this is not the best way of doing it.

I found this example, but this also includes all the values in the js file:

[Jquery Validator - check input against a list of accepted values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696222/jquery-validator-check-input-against-a-list-of-accepted-values)

```
    // post code check
    jQuery(function($) {

      // if user presses enter
      if ($('.home').length) {

        $('#postcode').keypress(function(e) {

          if (e.which == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $('#submit').click();
          };
        });


        $("#submit").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();


      var trim = $("#postcode").val();
      var val = trim.replace(/ /g, '');
      var upper = val.toUpperCase();
      var test = ["hello"]
      var arr = ["postcode1", "postcode2", "...postcode10,000"];
      if ($.inArray(upper, arr) !== -1) {
        alert('We Deliver To You!');
      } else {
        alert('Sorry we are not in your area yet');
      };
    });


  };
});
```

Comment: 10000 postcodes is a large file, I advice to do it at the serverside and fetch back the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to send ajax to backend and check in db if current  postcode is available to shipping. So you need :

- backend script to catch request
- table is db with all possible postcodes and flag(available or not)
- send ajax request to backend script

sql table for postcodes(example)

```
CREATE TABLE `postcodes` (
  `code` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `status` ENUM('NORMAL','DISABLED') NULL DEFAULT 'NORMAL',
  `created_at` INT NULL,
  `updated_at` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`code`));
```

simple jQuerycode to send ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { postCode:"some code"}
})
  .done(function( html ) {
    alert( "$.ajax done" );
    console.log(html)
  });
```